# SQL syntax error & combining strings error

Tags: php, mysql, json

Below is a segment of code (note not complete code) that receives a json object parses some info to an array and the arrays in the json object into a string by changing the array to string via implode and adding it to the pervious string.

There seems to be two problems occurring:

**1) it says 
    Array to string conversion in /posi_rest_service.php on line 36**

```
 $brontoJSONObject = $_POST['json'];
 $lineItems = ""; 
                $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($brontoJSONObject, TRUE)),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
                    if(is_array($val)) {
                            $lineItems .=  '(*)' . (implode("|", $val)); //this is 36!!!!!!!
                        } else {
                            array_push($dataArray, $val);
                            $aCount++;
                        }
                    }
                $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bronto_carts WHERE emailAddress = :emailAddress"); 
                $result->bindParam(':emailAddress', $dataArray[8]);
                $result->execute(); 
                $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn(); 
                if($number_of_rows > 0) {
                    $tmps = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM bronto_carts where emailAddress = :emailAddress");
                    $tmps->bindParam(':emailAddress', $dataArray[8]);
                    $tmps->execute();
                }
```

**EDIT new errors:**
Notice: Array to string conversion in /posi_rest_service.php on line 36

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /posi_rest_service.php on line 54

Comment: put :emailAddress in sigle quotes ':emailAddress'

Comment: No need for single quotes as it is a pdo prepared statement putting single quotes broke the sql

Comment: Maybe $val is an array inside array, try implode("|", $val[0]) or print_r($val) to see what it contains

Comment: Where is line 54? Did you solve the array to strong conversion error. That is probably because `$val` is an array.

Comment: It is an array in an array

Comment: Oh woops, I meant some elements of  `$val` might be arrays. You can `var_dump($val)` to find out

Comment: What is the proper way to handle it if the array has arrays in it?

Comment: Depends on what result you want. You may have to loop through `$val` instead of using implode e.g. `$r ='(*)';for($val as $v){if(is_array($v)){$r.=implode('|', $v);}else{$r.='|'.$v;}` Something like that, but that only works if `$val` isn't nested deeply.

Comment: I never used this: [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), but it might save you the trouble of writing recursive logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ignore it by use @. You can also try print_r( $val,true) instead of implode.

```
$brontoJSONObject = $_POST['json'];
$lineItems = ""; 
            $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($brontoJSONObject, TRUE)),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
            foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
                if(is_array($val)) {
                        $lineItems .=  '(*)' . (@implode("|", $val)); //this is 36!!!!!!!
                    } else {
                        array_push($dataArray, $val);
                        $aCount++;
                    }
                }
            $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bronto_carts WHERE emailAddress = :emailAddress"); 
            $result->bindParam(':emailAddress', $dataArray[8]);
            $result->execute(); 
            $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn(); 
            if($number_of_rows > 0) {
                $tmps = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM bronto_carts where emailAddress = :emailAddress");
                $tmps->bindParam(':emailAddress', $dataArray[8]);
                $tmps->execute();
            }
```